# Is it possible to open a gnome application group from the terminal

Tags: debian, terminal, gnome

Hello I was just wondering if there is any way to launch a gnome application group from the terminal right now the only way I see to do it is by going into activities and clicking on the desired group's icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. Just type the gnome command and put it in the background. For example:

```
gnome-terminal&
gnome-text-editor&
gnome-calculator&
```

If you type `gnome-` and then hit the `tab` key twice, bash will show you all the possible commands. \
On my machine I get:

```
$ gnome- # hit tab twice
gnome-calculator             gnome-keyring                gnome-session                gnome-system-log
gnome-character-map          gnome-keyring-3              gnome-session-inhibit        gnome-system-log-pkexec
gnome-contacts               gnome-keyring-daemon         gnome-session-properties     gnome-system-monitor
gnome-control-center         gnome-language-selector      gnome-session-quit           gnome-terminal
gnome-control-center.real    gnome-menus-blacklist        gnome-settings-daemon        gnome-terminal.wrapper
gnome-desktop-item-edit      gnome-open                   gnome-shell                  gnome-text-editor
gnome-disk-image-mounter     gnome-panel                  gnome-shell-extension-prefs  gnome-thumbnail-font
gnome-disks                  gnome-power-statistics       gnome-shell-extension-tool   gnome-tweak-tool
gnome-file-share-properties  gnome-screensaver            gnome-shell-perf-tool        gnome-wm
gnome-font-viewer            gnome-screensaver-command    gnome-sound-applet           gnome-www-browser
gnome-help                   gnome-screenshot             gnome-sound-recorder
```